# Getting return string from linux 'executable' in c++ program

Tags: c++, linux, qt, executable

I am developing a c++ program in which I need to get a string value of the image's path with its name like (/home/pi/downloads/.jpg) by calling an executable which is created by QT-4.8.7 to browse an image and select it.

When developing the GUI in QT, I have tried to return a string value from Qstring by converting it to the standard string using tostdString() function. There was no error in executing this QT program. For checking purpose, I have created a label to see the result string from Qstring variable. It is correct. After only I have used tostdString() function to convert it into a standard string and return that string value.

But when calling the executable of QT program in c++ to get the path and name of the image, there is no response for execution. 
   Is there any way to get a return string value from Linux executable or any other suggestion for this concept? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

```
std::string exec(const char* cmd) 
{
    char buffer[128];
    std::string result = "";
    FILE* pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    try 
    {
     while (!feof(pipe)) 
     {
        if (fgets(buffer, 128, pipe) != NULL)
            result += buffer;
     } 
    } 
    catch (...) 
    {
    pclose(pipe);
    throw;
    }
    pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}
```

This is the function I have found when I googling and tried to use.
 And I called this function via the statement below in a program.

```
string result= exec("./Browse");
```

'Browse' is the name I have given for executable that is created by QT.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "no response for execution". Can you post a small C++ outer program that attempts to use the Qt program?

Comment: So you basically have a demo of the file-chooser running, you want to select a file and print it to `stdout` so that it is "returned" on the command line?

Comment: C/C++ programs return an int back when they finish executing.  Are you talking about the value returned when you enclose it in backticks in a shell script, e.g. echo `ls *` where it would print the output of running the command ls *?  If so, then just print it to stdout.

Comment: @aschepler, response means, when c++ program is executed, GUI will open and I can select an image I need and that image will be displayed in the monitor.

Comment: I would use `system(cmd)` before the call to `popen` to make sure the command gets executed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, actually I am trying to pass the path of the file chosen to my C++ program; so trying to get the path in a string variable and pass that to another function in my C++ program

Comment: The confusing part is that Qt is simply a C++ library, you can call the file chooser from within your application, select the file, and have the complete path to the file selected available. That has been a basic part of the Qt tutorial since Qt3. If your Qt chooser is in a standalone program and you don't want to incorporate the choose in your code, then why not something like fork a process that executes the chooser and updates a string in your original program?